# Finding integers from a string array and printing it with created functions

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, multidimensional-array

I've been trying all week to solve this problem and now it seems that I myself don't seem to understand what's wrong: I can't use library functions to solve this, I need to create everything manually, please what am I missing or where did I get it wrong

Given a multi-line text (char text[20][81]) consisting of words and numeric values. A word is a continuous sequence of letters and / or numbers, and the rest are separators or numbers. From the text to highlight the entire positive numeric values which are not part of words. Do not modify the source text.

Implement and use a function that writes integers from the string str to the array numbers:

> `int getNumbers ( const char str[81], int numbers[40]);`

Input data: 
str-source string
Output data: 
numbers-array of integers contained in the source string
the return value is the number of integers

Implement and use a function that recognizes the first integer in a string:

> `int findInteger( const char str[81], char **end);`

Input data: 
 1. str - source string

Output data:

1. end - pointer to the character following the integer; if the integer is not detected, NULL is returned, the return value is a recognized integer

Format of input data. [M] [1st line] [2nd line] , etc. M is the number of lines in the text, an integer in the range [1, 20].

The format of the output. [1st number] [space] [2nd number], etc.; if there are no required numbers, type the message "no solution"

P.S. Add a test with a null value

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

int findInteger(const char str[81], char** end)
{
    int i, div, j, c;
    char num[81], **endc;

    if ((str[0] == 0) || (str[0] == 1) || (str[0] == 2) 
        || (str[0] == 3) || (str[0] == 4) || (str[0] == 5) 
        || (str[0] == 6) || (str[0] == 7) || (str[0] == 8) 
        || (str[0] == 9) || (str[0] == '\0') || (str[0] == ' ') 
        || str[0] == '!' || str[0] == '"' || str[0] == '\'' 
        || str[0] == ';' || str[0] == ':' || str[0] == '?' 
        || str[0] == '-' || str[0] == '.' || str[0] == ',' 
        || str[0] == ' ' || str[0] == '\n' )

    {
        div = 1;
    }

    else
    {
        div = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 81; i++)
    {
        if ((div) && ((str[i] == 0) || (str[i] == 1) || (str[i] == 2)
            || (str[i] == 3) || (str[i] == 4) || (str[i] == 5)
            || (str[i] == 6) || (str[i] == 7) || (str[i] == 8)
            || (str[i] == 9))) 
        {
            for (j = i; j < 81; j++) 
            {
                if ((str[j]) == 'a' || 'b' || 'c' || 'd' ||'e' ||'g'||'h'||'i'||'j'||'k'||'l'||'m'||'n'||'o'||'p'||'q'||'r'||'s'||'t'||'u'||'v'||'w'||'x'||'y'||'z') 
                {
                    j = 81;
                    endc = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (((!(str[j])) == ('a' || 'b' || 'c' || 'd' || 'e' || 'g' || 'h' || 'i' || 'j' || 'k' || 'l' 
                        || 'm' || 'n' || 'o' || 'p' || 'q' || 'r' || 's' || 't' || 'u' || 'v' || 'w' || 'x' || 'y' || 'z'
                        ||'1'||'2'||'3'||'4'||'5'||'6'||'7'||'8'||'9'||'0')) || ((j == (80)) && ((str[j] == 0) || (str[j] == 1) || (str[j] == 2)
                        || (str[j] == 3) || (str[j] == 4) || (str[j] == 5)|| (str[j] == 6) || (str[j] == 7) || (str[j] == 8)
                        || (str[j] == 9)))) 
                    {
                        for (i; i < j; i++) 
                        {
                            num[i] = str[i];
                            *endc == &str[j];
                            j = 81;
                        }

                        if ((j == (80)) && ((str[j] == 0) || (str[j] == 1) || (str[j] == 2)
                            || (str[j] == 3) || (str[j] == 4) || (str[j] == 5)
                            || (str[j] == 6) || (str[j] == 7) || (str[j] == 8)
                            || (str[j] == 9))) 
                        {
                            num[j] = str[j];
                            endc = 0;
                            j = 81;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    c = atoi(num); 
    return (c);        
}

int getNumbers(const char str[81], int numbers[40])
{
    int count = 0;
    char tmp = '\0';
    char* tmpstr = &tmp;
    strcpy(tmpstr, str);
    char** pEnd = &tmpstr;
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        numbers[i] = findInteger(tmpstr, pEnd);
        if (!*pEnd) { count++; }
        else { i++; tmpstr = *pEnd; }
    } while (*pEnd);
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    printf("start\n");
    char digit[20][81]; 

    char *num[81], *endc;
    int M; 
    scanf("%d", &M); 
    getchar(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) 
    {
        fgets(digit[i], 81, stdin);
    }

    int allCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) 
    {
        findInteger(digit[i] , &endc);
        allCount = i++;
        getNumbers(num[i], &M[&i]);
    }

    printf("%d", &endc);
    /*if (!allCount) 
    {
        printf("no solution\n");
    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's lots of instructions and code here. Can you narrow down what you're having trouble with?

Comment: I'm to create two functions, a function that writes integers from the string str to the array numbers: 
int getnumber ( const char str[81], int numbers[40]);, a function that recognizes the first integer in a string:

int find Integer( const char str[81], char **end); @Barmar

Comment: Output data:
numbers-array of integers contained in the source string
the return value is the number of integers


Output:
end-pointer to the character following the integer; if the integer is not detected, NULL is returned
the return value is a recognized integer @Barmar

Comment: Add the clarifications to the question, not comments.

Comment: So I've written the code, it's meant to take inputs find the integer with the help of functions and store in an array, and then print the integer found in the string, but surprisingly the code doesn't work, after I type in inputs it just does nothing else @Barmar

Answer (score 2):

First you must know about ASC II, check it [ASC II](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), it's says that every charater in C has an integer corresponding. For example, if check:

```
char letter = 'A'
if( (int)letter == 65)
   printf("It's me");
```

More precisely, the letter is a char type, but if you convert it to interger (int)letter the integer value is a number. 
This will help solve the problem. see that char 'A' is equally to an integer 65, and 'B' is 66, and 'C' is 67 ... that's means if you do

```
if( (int)letter >= 65 || (int)letter <= 90) 
   printf("I'm a capslock letter");
```

As letter = 'A', then it'll print.

OTHER thing that will help you is that '0' is different from 0.
'0' is a char value, and 0 is an integer. To find the numbers in your program will must to do it bellow:

The next program print the postion of a number in the string.

```
char str[] = "Today is 23 and yet 16PM";
int index = 0;
while(str[index] != '\0') {
 if(str[index] >= '0' && str[index] <= 9) {
    printf("I m a number, my postion is %d", index);
 }
 index = index + 1;
}
```

The end of every string is '\0', if you print it that will not show up, because it's only mark the end, but you can use it to iterate the string while you don't arrive the end.  The code start at position 0 (index = 0), and all string start at position 0. Bellow see the first letter of string:

```
printf("%c", str[0]);
```

With it you will be able to solve this problem.

The solution for writing the array of numbers:

```
int j = 0; // this hold index of array numbers

for(int i = 0; i < 81; ++i) {

   // if str is between this numbers, it's a separator
   if( (int)str[i] >= 32 && (int)str[i] <= 47) {

      i += 1;        // let's check the next char
      int lastj = j; // this save the last real numbers

      // while true is always true and run forever, until command break
      // edit: you can check end of string instead, in the while statment 
      while( true ) {

            // check if it a number
            if( (int)str[i] >= '0' && (int)str[i] <= '9') {
               numbers[j] = atoi(str[i]);
               j += 1;

            // check if it s a separator
            } else if((int)str[i] >= 32 && (int)str[i] <= 47) {
               break;
            } else {
               //if there's a letter on it, that is not a number!
               j = lastj; // "erase" numbers write into array
               break;
            }      
      }
   } 
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't hard-code ASCII values, use character constants. `if (str[index] >= 'A')`

Comment: In this case I use 32 because I forget the ASCII of separators, but I remember that around 32 and 47 we have a several of them. But it's true, it's not good code use hard values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the numbers in array to after getting out of function, you must provide a point to it. If you ask will explain pointers I will to, but in this code I saved the number in array numbers and I just returned the size of numbers.

```
int getNumbers ( const char str[81], int numbers[40]) {

 int j = 0; // this hold index of array numbers

 for(int i = 0; i < 81; ++i) {

   // if str is between this numbers, it's a separator
   if( (int)str[i] >= 32 && (int)str[i] <= 47) {

      i += 1;        // let's check the next char
      while( i < 81 ) {

            int number = 0;

            // check if it a number
            // if number is " 3433 "
            // we find add to number 0 * 10 + 3 = 0
            // then 30 + 4, after 340 + 3, after 3430 + 3
            // result is interger 3433
            if( (int)str[i] >= '0' && (int)str[i] <= '9') {
                number = (number * 10) + atoi(str[i]) ;

            // check if it s a separator, it's a number
            } else if((int)str[i] >= 32 && (int)str[i] <= 47) {
               numbers[j] = number;
               j += 1;
               break;
            } else {
               //if there's a letter on it, that is not a number!
               break;
            }      
      }
   } 
 }

     return j + 1; // the size of areay of numbers
}
```

The difference of this code is that if you have number 657, the  number saved will 657, not 6, 5, and 7 (separate numbers), like in previous code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use hard-code ASCII, it's not readable, instead use `if (str[index] >= 'A')`